# Override inherited function from c struct

Tags: c++, c, pointers, inheritance, struct

Alright, so I have this struct inside one.h

```
typedef struct NWK_DataReq_t
{
    uint16_t     dstAddr;
    uint8_t      options;
    uint8_t      *data;
    uint8_t      size;

    void         (*confirm)(struct NWK_DataReq_t *req);
} NWK_DataReq_t;
```

Later on, in two.h there are structs that inherit from `NWK_DataReq_t` with:

```
#include "one.h"

struct commandReq_t : public NWK_DataReq_t {
    ...
}

struct dataReq_t : public NWK_DataReq_t {
    ...
}
```

My goal is to inherit the structure of `NWK_DataReq_t` while setting default values for certain variables of `NWK_DataReq_t` and adding variables to the struct. So far, assigning defaults to the variables works as expected. The point I'm having trouble with is assigning the (*confirm)
function.

```
struct commandReq_t : public NWK_DataReq_t {
    uint16_t   dstAddress  = 2;
    uint8_t    options     = 8;

    void       confirm     = commandReqConf;

    char       newVar[20]   = "Hello";
} commandReq;

...

void commandReqConf(NWK_DataReq_t *req);
```

I have no idea how to set a default function to override it. My goal is to set `commandReqConf` as the `(*confirm)` function and pass it a `NWK_DataReq_t`.

I hope this makes sense, any help would be amazing.

Comment: C or C++?  They are two different languages.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Apparently initial struct was from C world (`void         (*confirm)(struct NWK_DataReq_t *req);` look like a C implementation of a virtual function), and OP wants to build C++ classes deriving from this initial struct. But `struct commandReq_t : public NWK_DataReq_t` is clearly C++.

Comment: @SergeBallesta You are correct.  I saw a lot of C-isms in the code so was not entirely sure what the OP was working with.

Comment: Right, the initial struct is written for C, while the second is C++11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, as you have written `struct commandReq_t : public NWK_DataReq_t {` and tagged the question as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you are now in c++ world.

IMHO, the simplest way to initialize an object is then in a constructor:

```
struct commandReq_t : public NWK_DataReq_t {
    commandReq_t() { // default ctor
        dstAddr = 2;
        options = 8;
        strcpy(newVar, "Hello");
        confirm     = &commandReqConf;
    }

    char       newVar[20];  // initialized at ctor initialization time
} commandReq;
...
static void commandReqConf(NWK_DataReq_t *req);
```

as the function `commandReqConf` is in fact member of a class `CzarController`, it should be static - but it need not to be qualified if it is contained in same class as is the struct.

Comment: Good ideas with the constructor, I forgot you can deal in this with structs - however this still throws an error for me with the confirm function: `error: cannot convert 'CzarController::commandReqConf' from type 'void (CzarController::)(NWK_DataReq_t*)' to type 'void (*)(NWK_DataReq_t*)'` Just for some context, my second struct is inside a class named `CzarController`

Comment: @maxmclau: if the member function `commandReqConf` can be static, the fix is easy (see my edit)

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
uint16_t   dstAddress  = 2;
uint8_t    options     = 8;

void       confirm     = commandReqConf;

char       newVar[20]   = "Hello";
```

in the definition of `commandReq_t` are members of the `struct`. They are additional members. They don't override the members in `NWK_DataReq_t`. Given that, the line

```
void       confirm     = commandReqConf;
```

is wrong on two accounts.

1. You cannot create a member variable of type `void`.
2. You cannot assign a function that returns a `void` to `confirm`.

What you need to do is set the values of the members in a constructor.

```
struct commandReq_t : public NWK_DataReq_t {

   commandReq_t()
   {
      dstAddr = 2;
      options = 8;
      confirm = commandReqConf;
      strcpy(newVar, "Hello");
   }
   char  newVar[20];
} commandReq;
```

Comment: This solution works correctly, but I'm still left without `commandReqConf` getting called since we use `nullptr`. Is there anyway to redirect this?

Comment: @maxmclau, that didn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, before you revised your answer you pointed confirm to `nullptr`. Now that we use `confirm = commandReqConf` I receive the same error as I did with @Serge Ballesta's answer below. It tells me I cannot convert to type `void (*)(NWK_DataReq_t*)`.

Comment: @maxmclau, please post the entire error message verbatim.

Comment: `In constructor 'CzarController::commandReq_t::commandReq_t()':
/Users/maxmillionmclaughlin/Moa/upland/libraries/czar/src/Czar.h:69:15: error: cannot convert 'CzarController::commandReqConf' from type 'void (CzarController::)(NWK_DataReq_t*)' to type 'void (*)(NWK_DataReq_t*)'
       confirm = commandReqConf;`

Comment: That's why we prefer to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not clear from the error message what's happening in your code.

Comment: Right, let me try to isolate the error so it fits that guideline

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You're trying to assign a member function of CzarController to confirm, but confirm is a pointer to a C function. You can't assign a pointer-to-member to a C-function pointer.